# Defining blocks of steps in Algorithmicx

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx, algorithmic

How can I define blocks and use Step, Input, and Output in Algoritmicx like the below image? In fact, I want to create this image exactly, but I have a problem with "Step".

[image: algorithm1]

I have no idea how to define these:

[image: algorithm2]

This is my what I have done so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,algorithm,tabularx,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\multiline}[1]{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\ALG@thistlm}[t]{@{}X@{}}
        #1
    \end{tabularx}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Dynamic Programming and Knapsack Problem}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \State $I = (w_1, \cdots w_n, c_1, \cdots c_n, b) \in (\mathbb{N}-\left\{0\right\})^{2n+1}$, $n$ a positive integer
            \Comment{Input}
            \State $TRIPLE(1) := \left\{(0, 0, \emptyset)\right\} \cup \{(c_1, w_1, \left\{1\right\}) | \; if \; w_1 \le b\}$
            \Comment{Step 1}
            \For {$i \leftarrow 1$ to $n-1$}
            \Comment{Step 2}
            \State {$SET(i+1):=TRIPLE(i)$};
            \For {$(k, w, T) \in TRIPLE(i)$}
            \If {$w+w_{i+1} \le b$}
            \State {$SET(i+1):=SET(i+1) \cup \left\{k+c_{i+1}, w+w_{i+1}, T \cup \left\{i+1\right\})\right\}$};
            \EndIf
            \EndFor
            \State \multiline{%
            Set $TRIPLE(i+1)$ as a subset of $SET(i+1)$ containing exactly one triple $(m, w', T')$ for every achievable profit $m$ in $SET(i+1)$ by choosing a triple with the minimal weight for the given $m$}
            \EndFor
            \State Compute $c:=max \{k \in \{1, \cdots, \sum_{i=1}^n c_i\} | (k, w, T) \in TRIPLE(n)$ for some $w$ and $T\}$
            \Comment{Step 3}
            \State The index set $T$ such that $(c, w, T) \in TRIPLE(n)$
            \Comment{Output}
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image: Algorithm3]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Thank you. I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try defining new commands while redefining the `alglinenumber`. Here is the code for your desired output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,algorithm,float,tabularx,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\multiline}[1]{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\ALG@thistlm}[t]{@{}X@{}}
        #1
    \end{tabularx}
}
\newcommand{\Input}[1]{\algrenewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{Input: \ \setcounter{ALG@line}{\numexpr##1-1}} #1}
\newcommand{\Step}[1]{\algrenewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{Step ##1: } #1}
\newcommand{\NoNumber}{\algrenewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{\setcounter{ALG@line}{\numexpr##1-1} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ }}
\newcommand{\Output}[1]{\algrenewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{Output:\setcounter{ALG@line}{\numexpr##1-1}} #1}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{3.2.2.2}
    \caption{(DPKP)}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Input \State $I = (w_1, \cdots w_n, c_1, \cdots c_n, b) \in (\mathbb{N}-\left\{0\right\})^{2n+1}$, $n$ a positive integer
        \Step \State $TRIPLE(1) := \left\{(0, 0, \emptyset)\right\} \cup \{(c_1, w_1, \left\{1\right\}) | \; if \; w_1 \le b\}$
        \Step \For {$i \leftarrow 1$ to $n-1$}
        \NoNumber \State {$SET(i+1):=TRIPLE(i)$};
        \For {$(k, w, T) \in TRIPLE(i)$}
        \If {$w+w_{i+1} \le b$}
        \State {$SET(i+1):=SET(i+1) \cup \left\{k+c_{i+1}, w+w_{i+1}, T \cup \left\{i+1\right\})\right\}$};
        \EndIf
        \EndFor
        \State \multiline{%
        Set $TRIPLE(i+1)$ as a subset of $SET(i+1)$ containing exactly one triple $(m, w', T')$ for every achievable profit $m$ in $SET(i+1)$ by choosing a triple with the minimal weight for the given $m$}
        \EndFor
        \Step \State Compute $c:=max \{k \in \{1, \cdots, \sum_{i=1}^n c_i\} | (k, w, T) \in TRIPLE(n)$ for some $w$ and $T\}$
        \Output \State The index set $T$ such that $(c, w, T) \in TRIPLE(n)$
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Note that to ensure all number tags are aligned, we have added extra spaces after tags with fewer characters, including the `NoNumber` command which includes an empty tag.